# Review App are not deployed automatically in Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I'm trying to set a pipeline that automatically creates a review build for my create-react-app which I can review from GitHub.

This is my `app.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "harry100-exercise",
  "scripts": {
  },
  "env": {
  },
  "formation": {
    "web": {
      "quantity": 1
    }
  },
  "addons": [
  ],
  "buildpacks": [
    {
      "url": "heroku/nodejs"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have created a pipeline and enabled auto deploying for the master branch.
But everytime I create a pull request on github, I have to manually click `create review app on heroku to view the review app`
Any help on this?

Comment: I have the same problem with https://github.com/AdventureLookup/AdventureLookup :(

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have "Wait for CI to pass" checked on the Review Apps setting page for the pipeline you are editing.

[image: This is a screenshot of the portion of the page containing the option to reload]